# grails War deploy error

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, tomcat7

I am using Tomcat7.0.20 and grails 1.3.7
i am getting this error while i am deploying the war file.

> Feb 25, 2013 1:54:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
>       INFO: Deploying web application archive IH-core.war
>       Feb 25, 2013 1:55:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
>       SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
>       org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/IH-core]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:932)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:723)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:470)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1363)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:294)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1242)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1400)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1410)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1389)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.mapper.Mapper.addWrapper(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)V
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3173)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3130)
>           at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1301)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1390)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:896)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:322)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
>           ... 15 more
>       Feb 25, 2013 1:55:35 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
>       SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive IH-core.war
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/IH-core]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:816)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:932)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:723)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:470)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1363)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:294)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1242)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1400)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1410)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1389)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Please help me in finding solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your servlet version settings in config.groovy, if I recall correctly.

Your error seems to be related to some tomcat code referenced by something in Grails.

Comment: Thanks for reply, The error is with tomcat the host server does not have grails support.